# Jenkins npm install not creating node_modules folder

Tags: jenkins, npm-install

I've created a job on our Jenkins server to build a NodeJS app using Gulp.  It pulls from bitbucket repo without any problems, but when the "npm install" is run in the Execute Windows batch command, it doesn't install the dependencies and the node_modules folder isn't created and if I try to run gulp it complains that gulp is not installed locally.  Below is the output I see when the Jenkins job is run.

```
C:\Jenkins\workspace\DCC Map>npm install 
audited 7781 packages in 5.271s
found 12 vulnerabilities (3 low, 9 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
[DCC Map] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins5832751157703772279.bat
C:\Jenkins\workspace\DCC Map>gulp
[[90m17:49:07[39m] Local gulp not found in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DCC Map
[[90m17:49:07[39m] Try running: npm install gulp
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Checking console output
Finished: FAILURE
```

If I go into the folder from a command prompt and run the npm install command the dependencies are installed correctly.  Something that I noticed is that in the Jenkins output it says "audited 7781 packages in 5.271s" vs when I run it from the command prompt it says "added 484 packages from 251 contributors and audited 7781 packages in 31.593s".

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6803

Basically if NODE_ENV is set to "production", npm install ignores dev dependencies.  A way to get around this is by executing npm install with the --production=false.